# What is the fuzz equivalent in Imagick PHP Gif optimization?

Tags: php, gif, imagick

I have a question on how to compress GIF to be smaller with Imagick PHP. Main issue is how to have it resample its color map to be smaller and generally add more compression.

Multiple guides for imagick sucggest using "-fuzz", but I have not seen any reference what the corresponding ImagickPHP method may be or if it is not implemented.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only somewhat similar operation I found was `quantizeImage`
https://www.php.net/manual/de/imagick.quantizeimage.php

However gif quality could only be controlled via color number and the results we emulated from another image service did something fancier.

Still not sure what the concrete relation to -fuzz option is in Imagick PHP

Answer (score 0):

Fuzz can be set as a parameter when using trim method.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.trimimage.php

Explanation:
A number of algorithms search for a target color. By default the color must be exact. Use this option to match colors that are close to the target color in RGB space. For example, if you want to automagically trim the edges of an image with -trim but the image was scanned and the target background color may differ by a small amount. This option can account for these differences.
Source: https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fuzz